# Virtual memory in operating system

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

A interviewer asked me that if i have 1 TB RAM and 10 TB HDD . Is there a need to implement virtual memory or not?.
Please tell me the correct answer as i m finding different answers on internet.

Comment: It depends: if you need to process a 2 TB dataset with an algorithm that doesn't know how to work off the disk, then yes.

Comment: Which did you find and what is your own reasoning on them? Please help avoiding unnecessary back and forth uncovering what you already know but didn't tell us.

Comment: I got answers that virtual memory is not required as ram is big enough . But interviewer asked me in objective way...that is to say YES or NO  if virtual memory  will be required or not

Comment: i think virtual memory is a great solution to many things, but it is never an requirement per se. even if you'd need the whole 11TB you could most likely find an other way, but a virtual memory layer might be a valuable solution. given only this question, I'd choose NO.

Answer (score 0):

First let us look at what is Virtual Memory:

```
Virtual memory is a common technique used in a computer's operating system 
(OS). Virtual memory uses both hardware and software to enable a computer 
to compensate for physical memory shortages, temporarily transferring data 
from random access memory (RAM) to disk storage.
```

What this means is that when RAM is insufficient (due to too many processes running in parallel, or memory heavy operations taking place, etc) computer smartly uses a part of Hard Disk as RAM storage. This solves the problem of insufficient RAM.

Now coming to the question, the question is incorrect, or rather a trickier one, as implementing virtual memory does not depend on the machine specs. What it depends on is that how much RAM is being utilised by the processes in your machine.

Comment: He asked me in yes or no. Wheteher u need virtual memory or not

Comment: That is not a valid question. But if I were at your place, I would've countered this question with another question. The answer of this can never be in Yes or No